# Neo4j.rb giving two types of object on same query (randomly)

Tags: neo4j.rb

**Neo4j version - 3.1.1**

**Neo4j.rb - 8.0.13**

**Rails - 4.2.2**

I am using these versions on local, somtimes same query is giving different results, I am noticing this issue from couple of days since I have tried to upgrade my application (Rails) but that's in seprate branch, Not sure what is going on here need help??

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to find the cause of it but found some workaround and have some research, this is only happing after I upgraded rails and only on the development env. If I do eager_load = true in development as well then it is working as expected, but it has some disadvantages as well after doing code changes I have to restart the server, etc. According to me, there is some file load issue

```
  config.eager_load = true
```